# How to stop animated gifs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, animated-gif

I wish that the .gif files would only show the first frame and never do any animation.

Also, I'd like this to work automatically (i.e. having to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> as in Firefox is not enough).

Is there a way of doing that in Chrome? I'm on a dev channel so I don't mind if it's an extension.

Comment: oh man this drives me crazy too! Why can't they support [ESC] like every other browser?

Comment: Yeah. I'd love this to be automatic, too -- like FlashBlock. I can't think of more than five occasions where the animation actually served some (good) purpose.

Comment: Actually I wish all browsers would support something like this option: stop animated gifs (and flash) by default but make it possible for the user to tell if the gif is an animated one or not, and provide a way to start the animation (or the flash) manually (maybe a clicking on the gif).

In short, stop animated gifs and flash by default but with graceful degradation.

Remote Desktop Connection users and anybody who's annoyed by seizure  inducing ads would be glad to see this feature realized!

Comment: You need to drop that and use **Opera**

Comment: Love uberhumor.com except for those animated GIFs posts.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this feature would be useful because GIF heavy sites (meme sites) lag the browser. _Especially_ on mobile.

Comment: This is a serious health issue for people with epilepsy.  It's unacceptable that major browsers do not offer a 100% reliable bullet-proof block animation / click-to-play option for people who are vulnerable to "snow crash" attacks over twitter, etc.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Apparently there are now the

- [Pause! Pause! Pause!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gpgcolmilkcnccpllfdleobpflemehec) and
- [Stop animations](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gemmknjnneiojfjelmgappppbaneikda#)

Chrome extensions.  Or perhaps the [Stop gif animations on escape](https://web.archive.org/web/20140408220028/http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/80588) user script?

Comment: The Stop Animations extension still exists, and still works - you have to hit Esc to enable and Esc againt before scrolling because of how it works by taking a screenshot.

Answer (score 8):

There is an issue for that in the tracker: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=3690

And a feature request in WebKit: http://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23945

Answer (score 6):

You can't, basically.  Not without using one of the options that require tiresome manual intervention.

"Pause Pause Pause!" stops GIF animations but is otherwise fundamentally broken -- it will, for example, get you blacklisted from Google searches due to excessive network activity or some such (I didn't debug it, but I sure got a lot of CAPTCHAs every time I tried to use Google!)

"Paused!" does not have that problem, but that seems to be largely because it doesn't actually seem to do anything at all.  GIFs still animate merrily away.

This seems unlikely to change any time soon.  It's already nearly two years since you asked this question, and there is *still* no reliable automatic solution in sight.  The Chrome bug is idling because WebKit does not support the necessary features.  The WebKit bug has basically not been touched since 2009.  The simple fact of the matter is this: you can use Chrome, *or* you can stop animated GIFs automatically, but not both at once.  Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

[Gif Jam (Animation Stopper)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gif-jam-animation-stopper/bclnijbemellankmoaafepibbboobalb)

This extension worked for me. Unlike most other extensions, it permanently disables gif animation (no need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> or other keys). Here is how it works:

> Http request to GIF images will be intercepted and replaced with a
>   version containing only the first frame of the image sequence.

Source code: [GitHub](https://github.com/adamfur/GifJam)

Answer (score 3):

In [this](https://techlogon.com/how-to-stop-animated-gifs-playing-in-ie-firefox-and-chrome/) article I found the [Animation Policy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/animation-policy/ncigbofjfbodhkaffojakplpmnleeoee/) by Google.

> Sad that they haven’t bothered to update it since 2015 but I guess if it ain’t broke…

For me it still works with Chrome 74. I prefer it due to security reasons:

> So the only one I’d recommend is Google’s own Animation Policy – it’s more secure and private as it only requires permission to ‘read and change your accessibility settings’ and it adds the option to display GIFs just once.

The policy is simple and it just works:

[image]

Comment: Why has this been removed from chrome :(

Comment: @djsmiley2kStaysInside Now it is available in Chrome.

Comment: I look forward to turning this back on \o/ I raised a bug for it, figured it'd get ignored but maybe it  was genuinely removed by accident then. :O

Answer (score 2):

Some notes at the Google Chrome Help -- [**Flashblock for Chrome**](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=3deb0874a3c8e9fc&hl=en)

---

Here is a jQuery reference for people who want to try writing their own chrome extensions.
[**Using jQuery to build Google Chrome extensions**](http://blog.michael-forster.de/2009/08/using-jquery-to-build-google-chrome.html)

Comment: Blocking flash does nothing for animated GIFs.

Answer (score 0):

One possible Way to stop gif animation is to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> to remove dropdown menu, <kbd>Alt</kbd> to resume.

Seems to work in the Google Chrome browser (Version 28.0.1500.95 m) (Windows XP) (08/16/2013).

Comment: this did not work at all for me in Chrome 40..