# How to pause/play animated gifs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, animation, animated-gif

I am interested in play/pause controls for gifs, like we have for videos(on Youtube, for example) or even for gifs on Reddit(gfycat player [RES extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reddit-enhancement-suite/kbmfpngjjgdllneeigpgjifpgocmfgmb)):
[image: reddit animation play pause controls]

I've googled and read other threads here on Super User but couldn't find a proper solution. People propose **[Pause! Pause! Pause!](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/gpgcolmilkcnccpllfdleobpflemehec)**(broken link); **[Stop animations](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gemmknjnneiojfjelmgappppbaneikda#)** and **[Gif Jam (Animation Stopper)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gif-jam-animation-stopper/bclnijbemellankmoaafepibbboobalb)** extensions for Chrome but that's not what I need.

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: **See Also**: [How to stop animated gifs in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/q/23655/180163)

Answer (score 8):

There are two Chrome Extensions that I've tried:

1. [**GIF Scrubber**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gif-scrubber/gbdacbnhlfdlllckelpdkgeklfjfgcmp?hl=en)
2. [**Play the GIF**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/play-the-gif/mchecalpedamcfhiadokofgomojakmki)

GIF Scrubber seems much more popular, but I chose Play the GIF because it adds the controls on the same window instead of opening a new tab/window.

Comment: I just tried GIF Scrubber. It works, but it does open a new tab/window instead of adding the controls on the same window.

Comment: Play the GIF is now dead. `404. That’s an error.`